# Why I cannot put a nsarray in uitableview cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsarray

I have this error:

```
[__NSArrayI length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8d06040
```

When I try and set a NSArray to the cell using the code:

```
cell.textLabel.text=[message objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Here is my code that starts as a NSDictionary:

```
NSDictionary *jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:LoginResponse options:0 error:&error];

NSLog(@"responseDataAfterNSDICT: %@", jsonDict);
//------------------------------------------
keys = [jsonDict allKeys];
values = [jsonDict objectsForKeys:keys notFoundMarker:[NSNull null]];

message = [values valueForKey:@"fromuser"];
NSLog(@"%@", message);
```

This is what my log is for the NSLog(@"%@", message);

```
2014-01-31 12:52:39.899 ArialCraft[16694:70b] (
    (
),
    (
    KyleUnrau
),
    (
    FixableMass09
)
)
```

It works with another NSArray, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Because a label's `text` is supposed to be an NSString, not an NSArray.  And what you're dumping above is an NSArray of NSArrays.  (Note the pair of `()` surrounding the whole thing -- that's the outer array.  Then there's a pair of `()` around each inner array, including the first empty one.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need one more subscript:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [[message objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] firstObject];
```

cell.textLabel.text is looking for an NSString object, not an NSArray object.